# Controller class contains too many methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am currently maintaining an application where unfortunately we have ended up in having too many Action methods. On top of this the architecture of this project is not fair from the beginning and every developer continued adding Business logic in the action methods of the Controller class instead of keeping it in another business layer.
So now one of our controller class has reached 15000 lines of code and I don't want to flood even more this class by adding another action method.

Any suggestions on how we can refactor this or can we use any partial controller class or any other better way?

N.B: I know we can use thin controllers by moving the code to another layer, but still we will end up with too many methods.

Comment: You could consider doing making this class a `partial`, and moving parts of this class to different files.

Comment: You can always have multiple controllers. It all depends on what you really need to do - it might very well be possible that you want a hundred different actions on one controller, and that's fine. But perhaps you'll find the actions don't really belong together, and you can separate the original controllers in several.

Comment: I don't see any reason why you couldn't write partial classes for the controller. I have never tried it but after all, it's just a class, same as any other, right? But that doesn't really solve your problem because in intellisense, class explorer, etc, it's still going to show the whole big list. I think you know the answer in your heart. Time to start refactoring into different, smaller, focussed controllers, and maybe watch the Pluralsight video on SOLID before you begin. And be ready for it to take several weeks...

Comment: I would look at separating the Action methods into controllers that properly backup the associated views. Further more, consider looking into the repository pattern and maybe dependency injection to better structure the business logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

15,000 lines, *jeez*.

Aside from what you've obviously stated about moving the code to the business layer (which you should do), I would also consider forming logical groups of those action methods that belong to a certain set of functions.

Once you've got these groups, create separate controllers for each of them, named appropriately. This way you'll clean up your controller and you'll also segregate sections of functionality into their own logical groupings.

Comment: Side note on grouping your controllers/actions, if this is a legacy application (been in the wild for awhile), you need to take note of the controller/actions you are moving and create URL rewrites or update your route table so your old URLs do not fail going forward.  Easy enough to do, but if you don't, you could affect people with bookmarked URLs and/or search engine rankings in the short term.

Comment: Thanks @mattytommo, yes this is a legacy app and this looks like a time taking approach and would add to cost and time. I was looking,for as quick as partial class thing to implement for the time.

Comment: @Maninder - you have to start somewhere if you want your app to be updated.  Why not start having the developers begin to add new features the new/more standard way (business layer, etc) and over time, refactor the troublesome controller(s) out into more meaningful logic groups?  Outside of reducing the file size, creating a partial class really doesn't buy you much IMHO.

Comment: Yes @mattytommo from now on we are going with business layer. With time we will be fixing the existing controllers .

Comment: @Maninder - PS, I am not MattyTommo :)  Awesome though, good luck going forward!

Comment: We had some outsourced over seas 'consultants' write some code for us and they delivered a _single method_ that had 12000 lines of code!!  (oO')

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Ahh, overseas "consultants". I have seen some dreadful code come from them to be honest, but 12,000 lines of code in a method has to be up there with the worse :O